# Fixed element is overflowing

Tags: css

I'm creating a modal.

Here is the fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/DzZsg/

I'm fixing a header to my modal using:

```
position: fixed;
```

I have two problems.

1. The header of the model needs to be fixed when the user scrolls down the model. But for some reason it's overflowing it's parent. Why?
2. Underneath the header is 'How can I stop this from being hidden under header?' this is hidden under the fixed header, how can I push the contents down?

Comment: Refer this link. Already answered. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18442628/position-fixed-width-100

Answer (score 0):

`position:fixed;` refers to window only , it is totally deconnected from flow or inheritance of your document.

What you look for needs a `position:absolute;` . A`padding` or `margin` for `#page` should be applied in order to free room  that absolute header already uses.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/DzZsg/2/)**

```
body {
    background: grey;
}
#modal {
    background: white;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 60%;
    left: 0;
    margin: auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 75%;
}
#page {
    padding-top:2em;
    background-color: #272822;
    color: white;
    overflow:auto;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    height:100%;
}
#header {
    background: tomato;
    border-bottom: 2px solid red;
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    right:17px;/* average 1 em */;
    left:0;
    height:2em;
}
p {
    padding-bottom: 50px;
}
```

Comment: But the header scrolls with the page in your example. I need it to stay at the top

Comment: @panthro , right, i fixed this and updatede the demo. scrolling is back on #page

Comment: Thanks but now the header does not fill the full width of the modal

Comment: tune the right coordonates to 0, but it will show over the srolling bar

Comment: @panthro else , do not use absolute position but regular flow http://jsfiddle.net/DzZsg/3/ you can as well use calc() to tune height if header's height is known http://jsfiddle.net/DzZsg/4/

Comment: Actually your regular flow example does not work. You have specified a height for the header. So this won;t work with dynamic content.

Comment: you could use the magic  flex propertie ... http://jsfiddle.net/DzZsg/6/ and an extra line in header does http://jsfiddle.net/DzZsg/7/ , avalaible for young browser

Comment: @panthro you could use the magic flex propertie ... http://jsfiddle.net/DzZsg/6 and an extra line in header does http://jsfiddle.net/DzZsg/7 , avalaible for young browser other options : http://jsfiddle.net/DzZsg/8 http://jsfiddle.net/DzZsg/9

Answer (score -1):

in the style #header use "width: 371px;" rather than "width:100%;"