# Position:fixed toolbar in a div next to a dynamic width side nav

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a side nav that can be collapsed. I want my toolbar div to be fixed to the top and fill the rest of the width. 100% causes it to go off the page. I can't do a calc() because of the dynamic width of the sidenav.

How can I set a position: fixed div to fill the remaining width?

This is really hard to make a fiddle for, I'm using angular but basically:

```
<body layout="row">
  <div layout="column" class="menu">
    Menu
  </div>
  <div class="view">
    <div class="toolbar">
       I'm a toolbar
    </div>
    Rest of the stuff on the page
  </div>
</body>

.menu {
  height: 100%;
  width: 300px; //current width anyway
}
.view {
  width: 100%;
}
.toolbar {
  background-color: grey;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  height: 60px;
}
```

The problem looks similar to this guy: [Position Fixed width 100%](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18442628/position-fixed-width-100)

But I have the issue of the dynamic side nav

Comment: Please add a minimal Example-Snippet of your problem. Especially your CSS and HTML.

Comment: It would help to see the CSS classes too probably.

Answer (score 0):

If you set the CSS `right` property on the element with `position: fixed`, it will not go past the edge of the page:

```
right: 0;
```

Make sure you remove the `width: 100%` as well.